# laravel 9 " `C:\XAMPP\tmp\php6CB6`.`tmp`, " issue when uploading image

Tags: php, laravel-9

```php
$request->validate([

'title' => 'required|unique:latests|max:255',
'description' => 'required',
'image' => 'required','mimes:jpg,png,jpeg', 'max:5048']);`


    if($request->file('image')){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $image_gen = hexdec(uniqid()). '.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($image)->resize(322, 500)->save(public_path('upload/image-folder/'. $image_gen));
    $save_url = 'upload/image-folder'. $image_gen;`


}
    $latest = new Latest();
    $latest->title = $request->title;
    $latest->description = $request->description;
    $latest->$image = $save_url;
    $latest->save();`
```

Here is the image for error column in database:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried also this one :

```php
'local' => ['driver' => 'local', 'root' => public_path(),
```

Unfortunately it didn't work i don't

Comment: Isn't this a typo: `$latest->$image`? Shouldn't it be `$latest->image`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , I already solved this issue.